# how to solve nonlinear with BBsolve

Tags: r, math, stat

I tried to solve a nonlinear system using BBsolve, but it did not work i got this:

```r
Error in optim(par = par, fn = U, method = "Nelder-Mead", control = list(maxit = 100), :
function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters
Error in BBsolve(par = c(0.9, 1.9, 1.4), fn = g) :
object 'ans.best' not found
```

Then when I used `dfsane` and `sane` I got this :

```r
Iteration:  0  ||F(x0)||:  7531.03 
Error in R > dfsane(par = c(0.9, 1.9, 1.4), fn = g, control = list(trace 
= TRUE)) : 
comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In log(q[1]) : NaNs produced
2: In log(Xr/q[1]) : NaNs produced
3: In log(Xr/q[1]) : NaNs produced
4: In dfsane(par = c(0.9, 1.9, 1.4), fn = g, control = list(trace = 
TRUE)) :
Unsuccessful convergence.
```

Is there no other way to solve the system?

Comment: Hi Hiba! Please show your original function calls and provide some test data with `dput(df)` so we can start helping you

Comment: This means that your initial guess might be outside of the feasible region. Adding the function to be optimized in the question's description would also be helpful for us to help you.

Comment: well the function is so long and complicated that is why i did not put it, and the system's solution should be an approximation, so it is not i guessed the solution i just did put a value near the real ones. i did some changes and now some times it give me a successful convergence and sometimes no, my problem is : i need to repeat the operation many times, so is there a way when it always gives me a successful convergence ???

Comment: The term "initial guess" is a generic term that means the initial approximate solution, whatever the method you used to get it. It does not mean that you guessed the solution out of the blue. Since we don't have access to the full function, it will be hard to go further. Try to evaluate the function (without optimizing) with the initial parameter and see if there is any singularity/NaNs/division by zero/instability at this point. If there is, then you will need a better initial guess.

Comment: well, thank you for the information, i do study mathematics in french, so i took what you said literally,  thus changing the initial guess would be the solution, i really do appreciate your help.

Comment: hello, i just noticed that i can not extract the solutions of the system one by one, is there a way to do that ??, it is like they are considered as one element,